# How to get direct links to the files uploaded via script?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, openshift

I'm able to upload files successfully via PHP to /app-root/data/

Now I want a direct link for the files uploaded so that we can download it via http (I mean my web application)

I want that "xyz.txt" is uploaded to /app-root/data/xyz.txt and need a direct link like https://app-name.rhcloud.com/data/xyz.txt

How can I do it? pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, What I did is login to ssh console of my app and created a link like

```
ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php/data
```

And uploaded file's direct links are like
https://app-name.rhcloud.com/data/???.??

Comment: great solution, Mazhar Ahmed.

Comment: Anyway, every push to openshift will overwrite all links, so you will not get the file links after next push.

There is a solution
just put this linking shell command to
.openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy
Thus it will be performed every time after pushing and links will be restored